# Multivariate, nonlinear regression in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression

I am trying to make a chemical concentration curve, but it has been so long since I have had to use any type of math I'm having trouble getting going through iterations to find the best fit.

The data has one dependent variable, $y$, and two independent variables $x_1$ and $x_2$. However $x_1$ and $x_2$ do interact with each other. One concentration, $y$, is represented by a nonlinear curve made up by $x_1$ and $x_2$.

[image: The image is what the curves usually look like.]

Each curve in the image shown represents a different concentration. The goal is to be able to gather $x_1$ and $x_2$ and determine what concentration, $y$ the solution is.

What methods should I start with? Should I just stick with polynomial or try PLS or PCA? I'm worried about over-fitting the data since in the real life application there will be some day to day testing variability that the regression needs to account for.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If your question is *only* 'how to get R to do this', it is off topic here. If you have a statistical question, please edit to clarify. It may help you to read some of our existing threads [tagged w/ r & nonlinear-regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonlinear-regression+r?sort=frequent&pageSize=50).

Comment: Also, this is not multivariate regression (which implies more than one dependent variable).  This is multiple regression (more than two independent variables).

Also, you should clarify what you mean by PLS or PCA?  Different fields have different abbreviations so you should spell out acronyms the first time you use them.  

One question I'd have too is how much data do you have available to you?

Should we assume $x_1$ and $x_2$ are continuous random variables greater than 0?